# PHP Foreach Parallel Socket Connections?

Tags: php, sockets, foreach, parallel-processing

I have a script that connects to a list of servers in a foreach loop using an associative array with the ip address as the key and port number as the value. I write a small amount of data to the socket then read back the response from the server. There are usually 5-15 servers in the array and each transaction can take a few hundred milliseconds which quickly adds to the waiting time for the user. Is there a way I can execute the connections in parallel so the users don't have to wait as long?

```
foreach ($clients as $network_address => $port)
{
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    if ($socket === false) {
        continue;
    }

    $result = socket_connect($socket, $network_address, $port);
    if ($result === false) {
        continue;
    }

    socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data));

    $response[$network_address] = socket_read($socket, 2048);

    socket_close($socket);
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-nonblock.php might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [socket_select](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php)(**array** &*$read* , **array** &*$write* , **array** &*$except* , **int** *$tv_sec* [, **int** *$tv_usec* = 0 ]) is the best way, to talk to more then one host.